# sql server 2008 reporting services

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, expression

I'm trying to generate a matrix report. I have an SSN row and a 3 digit code column. The 3 digit codes are randomly inserted into cells through out the report, one per row. I would like to have them display all in one column. I have tried...

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!CODE.Value),"The Field Is Null",Fields!CODE.Value)
```

But this just displays "The Field is Null". I want noting displayed as in...

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!CODE.Value),"",Fields!CODE.Value)
```

But have the null cells themselves excluded. Anyone know a trick to pull this off?

the result would look like this...

```
ssn          code
123456789    123
123456789    123
and so on
```

My matrix structure looks like this...
[image]

and the Exp is now set to =Iif(IsNothing(Fields!ID5.Value),"The Field Is Null",Fields!ID5.Value)
Note: The ID5 is just a quick nameing convention. ID5 corresponds to the code. ID2 corresponds to the SSN.

Comment: Can you please add what your data look like when it get to the report and a bit more info on what you want to display. You seem to say you want to display the codes but then say you don't???

Comment: So Fields!CODE.Value can either: have a value; have an empty string value; be NULL? And you want the NULLs and empty strings to display the same?

Comment: I actually want the null cells to go away hehe! I was just using the Iif command as a starting point. I do want to display the code values but they are dispursed. One per row, in one of around 20 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to compress several columns into one column excluding the null columns?

Probably the easiest way is to do it in the query:

```
SELECT SSN, IsNull(Code1, '') + IsNull(Code2, '') + IsNull(Code3, '') AS Code
FROM MyTable
```

Alternatively, do it in the expression in Reporting Services:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Code1.Value), "", Fields!Code1.Value) + IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Code2.Value), "", Fields!Code2.Value)
```

and so on...

Comment: I could use this in the earlier parts of building the reports but I was trying to find an expression to do this after I've queried the dataset.

Comment: Unless, of course, If you knew how to write that as an acceptable expression. I don't, but my skill level is very low!

Comment: Just use IIF(IsNothing(... as described in the answer now